# Validate jQuery with direct input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

This is probably a dumb question, but does anyone know where I can validate jQuery using direct input?

I'm looking for something like the [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/), or [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/), where I can paste in jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is Javascript, you can just use jsLint?

Comment: doesn't work for me... if I paste jQuery into jsLint I get millions of errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is really nice. 
http://jsfiddle.net/